# ¿Pasar un parámetro XML desde laravel a un Stored Procedure en Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, laravel

Tengo este XML, que lo he dibujado con laravel:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Results>
   <BoxList>
      <IdTipoCaja>1</IdTipoCaja>
      <Numero>4929</Numero>
      <TotalTarjetas>500</TotalTarjetas>
      <SerieInicial>27307301</SerieInicial>
      <SerieFinal>27307800</SerieFinal>
   </BoxList>
   <BoxList>
      <IdTipoCaja>1</IdTipoCaja>
      <Numero>4930</Numero>
      <TotalTarjetas>500</TotalTarjetas>
      <SerieInicial>27307801</SerieInicial>
      <SerieFinal>27308300</SerieFinal>
   </BoxList>
   <BoxList>
      <IdTipoCaja>1</IdTipoCaja>
      <Numero>4931</Numero>
      <TotalTarjetas>500</TotalTarjetas>
      <SerieInicial>27308301</SerieInicial>
      <SerieFinal>27308800</SerieFinal>
   </BoxList>
</Results>
```

Cree el siguiente Stored Procedure en Sql Server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE IT_SP_CARGA_ARCHIVO
    @InputXML XML
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @IdTipoCaja INT
    DECLARE @Numero INT
    DECLARE @TotalTarjetas INT
    DECLARE @SerieInicial INT
    DECLARE @SerieFinal INT 

    DECLARE Cajas CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR       
        SELECT
            Results.BoxList.value('IdTipoCaja[1]','INT') AS IdTipoCaja,
            Results.BoxList.value('Numero[1]','INT') AS Numero,
            Results.BoxList.value('TotalTarjetas[1]','INT') AS TotalTarjetas,
            Results.BoxList.value('SerieInicial[1]','INT') AS SerieInicial,
            Results.BoxList.value('SerieFinal[1]','INT') AS SerieFinal      
            FROM @InputXML.nodes('Results/BoxList') Results(BoxList)    
    OPEN Cajas
        FETCH Cajas INTO @IdTipoCaja,@Numero,@TotalTarjetas,@SerieInicial,@SerieFinal
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            BEGIN                   
                FETCH Cajas INTO @IdTipoCaja,@Numero,@TotalTarjetas,@SerieInicial,@SerieFinal
            END
    CLOSE Cajas 
    SELECT 'YA SE CREO CURSOR' AS XML_FILE
END
```

Lo llamo desde Laravel:

```
$cargaArchivo = DB::connection("sqlsrvit")->select("EXEC IT_SP_CARGA_ARCHIVO ?",array($drawXML));
```

Cuando lo ejecuto desde la base de datos de Sql Server (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) si funciona a la perfección.

Pero cuando lo ejecuto desde Laravel me muestra el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1934 General SQL Server error: 
Check messages from the SQL Server [1934] (severity 16) [(null)]
```

Realmente no se cual es la falla, pero si alguien puede ayudarme con el tema, estaré completamente agradecido.

Comment: Como construiste el XML??, por que al hacerlo de la misma forma me envía el siguiente mensaje "SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@P1'. (SQL: call test_sp(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Results><BoxList><IdTipoCaja>1</IdTipoCaja><Numero>4929</Numero></BoxList></Results>))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la respuesta.

Se debe incluir lo siguiente al inicio del SP

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```